Why does Spotless not break long lines though configured to do so?
We have a Java file with content like this (the "real" code does not matter):
public class Example {
    public void doSomething(List<String> list) {
        try {
            if (doesNotMatter) {
                list.forEach(item -> {
                    // The following line exceeds 120 characters in length:
                    item.contains("a very very long string") ? doSomethingWithItem(item) : doSomethingElseWithItem(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When using Spotless to format the file, I'd suppose it would break the long line at a reasonable position, such that it'll be shorter than 120 characters, but it does not.
Even worse, if I manually break the line, Spotless will re-assemble it as it was before. (I'm aware of the possibility to avoid this using an empty comment (//) after the first part of the line.)
The question is, why is Spotless ignoring the 120 character rule?
I'm using Spotless as Gradle plugin configured like this in build.gradle (relevant parts only):
plugins {
  id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.25.0'
}

spotless {

  java {
    eclipse().configFile(rootProject.file('codeformat.xml'))
    formatAnnotations()
    trimTrailingWhitespace()
    removeUnusedImports()
    indentWithSpaces(4)
  }

}

The codeformat.xml file was exported from my IntelliJ code formatting settings and contains these lines:
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit" value="120"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.line_length" value="120"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.line_length" value="120"/>

